# D3 Force Directed Graph nodes in order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using the Force Directed Graph to build a kind of flow diagram. It works fine except that the nodes have no specific order. They are random. I would like the graph to follow a hierarchical order.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(90)
    .gravity(0.6)
    .charge(-2000)
    .linkStrength(0.3);
```

I want to give the nodes some (numerical) hierarchy. Not explicitly define their placement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "order"? Do you want to control the placement of the nodes or create a hierarchical structure?

Comment: I think using simple "Force Directed Layout" and having a hierarchy does not go well together at all. For flow diagrams and hierarchical orders you should take a look at Sugiyama based algorithms like this one: [Hierarchical layout Demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.1/demos/Complete/demo.yfiles.layout.incrementalhierarchiclayouter/index.html) - this is not D3, though and hence just a comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the force layout with a *quantitative foci* so the nodes are located based in its numerical hierarchy. A demo from Mike's [talk](http://vimeo.com/29458354) (and the code):

- [Demo](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/#19)
- [Code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/gh-pages/talk/20110921/quantitative-foci.html)

Regards

Comment: With *quantitative focii* you still have to explicitly define the locations of the focii, this is what the OP was trying to avoid. Also I don't see how the linked demo is related to either of this.

Comment: If a node has more than one parent, a hierarchical layout can't be used. The demo shows how the nodes in a force layout can be displayed in different vertical positions depending on a numerical attribute (of course, a mapping from the numerical hierarchy to the vertical position is still needed). The demo doesn't show the links, but it's easy to add them.

Comment: In graph drawing terms "hierarchical layouts" are used to describe not only simply tree-like structures. Any number of parents and children is allowed here. I was under the impression that the OP was looking for a [Sugiyama styled hierarchical layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing). In that case you do not have to specify any coordinates, the "numerical hierarchy" can be directly mapped to the layers in the drawing - the exact coordinates are then determined by the algorithm.