# D3: Links between spouses in a family tree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree

Here is the link for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mj58659094/ADXGu/`;`

Right now family tree has only links between parent-child.  How can I get links between spouses like below?

```
                                        |-----------------------|       
                                  - - - | Father-3 (SMJ)        |       
                               -        |                       |-      
                             -          |-----------------------|  -    
|-----------------------|  -                                        -   
| Father-0 (PMI)        |-              |-----------------------|    -  
|                       |-              | Mother-3 (AJ)         |  -  - 
|-----------------------|  -            | (AJ Nickname)         |-    - 
                            -           |-----------------------|    -  
|-----------------------|   -                                       -   
| Mother-0 (MP)         |  -            |-----------------------|  -    
| (AJ Nickname)         |-              | Mother-3 (MTJ)        | -     
|-----------------------|               | (MTJNickname)         |-      
                                        |-----------------------|
```

personId: "1000101" Father-3 (SMJ) married two times, first wife was personId: "1000102" Mother-3 (AJ), and second wife was personId: "1000103" Mother-3 (MTJ).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Would something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094) be of any use?

Comment: @user1614080 Thanks for your response.  The link you provided only contains parent-child realationship, NO spouses.  Mine deals with spouses as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may locate the spouses as children of the father (D3 don't care about that), but as you are linking the children to the father only, the spouse will appear at the same level that the children:

```
Father 0 ---- Spouse 0-0
         ---- Spouse 0-1
         ---- Spouse 0-2
         ---- Father 1 ---- Spouse 1-0
                       ---- Father 2
```

Another solution may be to link the children to the spouse:

```
Father 0 ---- Spouse 0-0 ---- Father 1 ---- Spouse 1-0 ---- Father 2
         ---- Spouse 0-1
         ---- Spouse 0-2
```

I suspect that you will need a different layout (the [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout), for instance), to express that the children have two parents:

```
Spouse 0-2
   |
   |
Father 0 ---- Spouse 0-0 
   |    \         /    
   |      Father 1 ------ Father 2
   |          \           /
Spouse 0-1      Spouse 1-0
```

and you may want to differentiate the links from parents to children from the links from husbands and wives.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I want the spouses to be at the same level as the husbands or wifes.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider using the force layout with quantitative foci (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293595/d3-force-directed-graph-nodes-in-order), so the same generation is located at the same vertical position and to allow more than one parent for each child.